# Center text in td element based on 2. td element in previous tr element

Tags: html, css

I have the folowing:

```
<tr>
  <td class="neighbor">
   text
  </td>
  <td id="aim">
   text 
  </td>
  <td class="neighbor">
   text text
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="text" colspan="3">
   some long text
  </td>
</tr>
```

How do I let the content of #text be centered based on #aim? note that .neighbor tds are not equal spaced.

Comment: You'd need Javascript for that. It's not possible with CSS.

Comment: That was my guess to ;) But I was hoping for a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply fill in the blank  tags on either side of text instead of using a colspan. This will place the columns beneath each other.

```
css:
#aim, #text
{
    text-align: center;
}

html:
<tr>
  <td class="neighbor">
   text
  </td>
  <td id="aim">
   text 
  </td>
  <td class="neighbor">
   text text
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  </td>
  <td id="text">
   some long text
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
</tr>
```

If your goal is not to center the text in this way please provide a quick image of how it should look.

Comment: #aim is column2 in the first row. Thus placing #text in the same column will achieve that. Basic css text-align: center on both ids if they actually want all the text centered in the cell would go even further. If the question is more complicated than that it needs more explanation and a diagram to explain.

Comment: Thinking now, the meaning of centered in this context is quite vague. Aligning the columns is one interpretation, centering the cell text is another. Even moreover the op could be referring to something all together more complex where a table is not the right solution.